# Show div relative to it's parent top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs which have absolute positioned sidebars that show at their right when hovered.
I want each sidebar to show at 100px from the top from it's parent top position when hovered.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="guide-container">
   THIS IS THE PARENT DIV
 <aside class="guide-extras">
   THIS IS THE SIDEBAR
 </aside>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $( ".guide-container" ).hover(function() {
          var container = $( this ).find("aside").toggle();
          var height =  $( this ).find("aside").position().top
          $( this ).find("aside").css("top", height);
    });
```

Comment: Is it okay if the div's are floated left and right?

Comment: Or are they `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: The divs are in display:none because they will only show when their parent is hovered

Comment: My answer should work, I added a JSFiddle that works.

Comment: Please could you select my answer as the correct answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using only CSS:

```css
.guide-extras {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.guide-container:hover > .guide-extras {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="guide-container">
   THIS IS THE PARENT DIV
 <aside class="guide-extras">
   THIS IS THE SIDEBAR
 </aside>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="guide-container">
   THIS IS THE PARENT DIV
 <aside class="guide-extras">
   THIS IS THE SIDEBAR
 </aside>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ojq6fvk/1/)

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm, didn't think about it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please select the answer as the correct one once you can if it worked for you. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Why JavaScript? You can do it with plain CSS:

```css
.guide-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 50%;
}

.guide-extras {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -210px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #00f;
  display: none;
}

.guide-container:hover .guide-extras {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="guide-container">
   THIS IS THE PARENT DIV
   <aside class="guide-extras">
     THIS IS THE SIDEBAR
   </aside>
</div>
<div class="guide-container">
   THIS IS THE PARENT DIV
   <aside class="guide-extras">
     THIS IS THE SIDEBAR
   </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply adding `margin-top: 100px;` to the `.guide-extras` CSS class.

Comment: That will show all of the sidebars in the same position, I need each sidebar to show relatively to its parents top position